# Unable to insert into or update table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, locking, dbcc

A have the following table in a SQL Server 2000 database (service pack 2), with about 600,000 rows:

```
Id [int, primary key]  
Form [int]  
Element [int]  
Data [char(8000)]  
MoreData [varchar(8000)]
```

(I should note: the "Data" column probably holds less than 30 characters for almost every row. No idea why char(8000) was chosen previously.)

A simple `INSERT INTO` query with a single row of data was timing out on my website, and attempting to perform the same query directly in SQL Server Management Studio was fruitless after over 20 minutes of waiting. I ran `DBCC SHOWCONTIG` and received the following:

```
DBCC SHOWCONTIG scanning '(Table Name)' table...  
Table: '(Table Name)' (926730454); index ID: 0, database ID: 8  
TABLE level scan performed.  
- Pages Scanned................................: 2555  
- Extents Scanned..............................: 328  
- Extent Switches..............................: 327  
- Avg. Pages per Extent........................: 7.8  
- Scan Density [Best Count:Actual Count].......: 97.56% [320:328]  
- Extent Scan Fragmentation ...................: 99.39%  
- Avg. Bytes Free per Page.....................: 349.8  
- Avg. Page Density (full).....................: 95.68%  
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.
```

Thinking fragmentation was the problem, I ran `DBREINDEX` on the table for over two hours with no luck. After searching further, I also executed `sp_lock` and found over a million EXT (extent) locks, the bulk being attributed to the SPID for the website (same credentials I used to connect to the database in Management Studio). Most of the remainder were by SPID 123, which didn't come up using `sp_who`.

Is that number of locks (a million, for a fairly low traffic website) strange? Could they be caused by my attempts to rebuild the index when I killed the Management Studio window two or three times (for not responding)? Or could this be a problem with the physical drive?

---

Since gathering the above information a few hours ago the number of locks has dropped to only 16, and the table is working normally again. If anyone can help I'd still like some insight into what caused the problem so that it can be prevented in the future.

Comment: Sql Server 2000 SP2 was released in [2003](http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/). How about an upgrade or even an update? You are missing *a lot* fixes.